# Spring JPA Update and Return the Updated Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How to build a JPA method that could return the updated data when updateing using JPA query?
I have created something like this.

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE User u SET u.isActive = true"
      + " WHERE u.isActive = false AND u.reactivateTime <= currentTime"
      + " AND u.reactivateTime IS NOT null")
int reactivateUser(@Param("currentTime") ZonedDateTime currentTime);
```

But, what I want is it is returning list of user. If I directly changed it to something like this

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE User u SET u.isActive = true"
      + " WHERE u.isActive = false AND u.reactivateTime <= currentTime"
      + " AND u.reactivateTime IS NOT null")
List<User> reactivateUser(@Param("currentTime") ZonedDateTime currentTime);
```

It will become error like this.

```
IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations
```

Comment: Update operation doesn't fetch any data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, just changing the return type of your method doesn't cause the auto-generated JPA method to return a different type.

The problem is that you are doing a bulk update operation. This is going to get turned into an equivalent SQL "update...where" statement at execution time, and the only data that is going to be returned by JDBC is the number of rows updated. (And BTW, in that case, you should return a long, not an int).

So, you have to devise some other way of doing this.
Off-hand, I can think of two ways:

1. If you can be pretty certain that you will always be updating a relatively small number of rows (say, a up to a few hundred), then you could create a method that selects the Entity instances that you want to update, e.g.

   ```
   @Query("SELECT u from User" + " WHERE u.isActive = false AND u.reactivateTime <= currentTime" + " AND u.reactivateTime IS NOT null")
   List<User> getUsersToReactivate(@Param("currentTime") ZonedDateTime currentTime);
   ```

And then, in a concrete implementation of the JPA Repository interface,

- Call the method to retrieve the entities.
- Update the entities via java code
- Save the entities

For example (I just typed this, didn't try it - syntax errors are your responsibility):

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
List<User> reactivateUsers(ZonedDateTime currentTime) {
   List<User> users = getUsersToReactivate(currentTime);
   users.forEach(user -> {
       user.setActive(true);
       save(user);
   ); 
   return users; 
}
```

2. This may be more intrusive, but you could add a Date property to the User class called 'lastUpdated', get the current date, update the isActive flag to true and the 'lastUpdated' property to the current date, and then select entities where the lastUpdate property is the current date.