# Spring Data Repository @Query - Update and return modified List

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

let's assume we have a Spring Data repository interface with a custom method.

```
static final string UPDATE_ENTITY =
"""UPDATE entity SET updated_on = :updatedDateTime, updated_by = :createdBy, company_id = :targetId where company_id = :sourceId""";

@Query(value = UPDATE_ENTITY, nativeQuery = true)`
@Modifying
@Transactional
int transferEntity(String sourceId, String targetId, Timestamp updatedDateTime, String createdBy);
```

This method simply sets the updated field of the entity, ok. Is there any way to return list of <entity> instead of returning count i.e int/void?

Obviously...I tried

```
@Query(value = UPDATE_ENTITY, nativeQuery = true)
@Modifying
@Transactional
List<Entity> transferEntity(String sourceId, String targetId, Timestamp updatedDateTime, String createdBy);
```

does not work, since..

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Modifying queries can only use void or int/Integer as return type!

Does anyone know another way to return the list of updated entity ids?

Comment: you can refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61472442/spring-jpa-update-and-return-the-updated-data  ..... Modifying query always returns the number of rows that has been updated because under the hood only one update query will execute with where clause.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49690671/spring-data-repository-query-update-and-return-modified-entity?noredirect=1&lq=1 refer this link.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says Modifying queries can only use void or int/Integer as return type you can only return void or an integer/int that signify how many rows has been updated by the query.

So you can't return à list of objects with this method

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@Query` annotation to execute custom update queries, and return the modified list of entities using the `RETURNING` keyword **for databases that support it**.

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
    
    @Query(value = "UPDATE my_entity SET my_field = :newValue WHERE id IN :ids RETURNING id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Long> updateMyFieldByIdsAndReturnIds(@Param("newVal") String newVal, @Param("ids") List<Long> ids);
}
```

Note that the `nativeQuery` attribute of the `@Query` annotation is set to `true` to indicate that we are using a native SQL query instead of a JPQL query. Also, make sure to use the correct syntax for your database when using native queries.

This method returns a list of `Long` values which represent the ids of the entities that were updated and it is important that you database support this concept

Comment: I tried this but getting error as below
{
    "message": "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet",
    "path": "/api/v1/notes/note-transfer"
}